# JpGraph with multiple graphs inside a for loop

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm attempting to create yearly and monthly graphs by using a for loop with JpGraph.  I've read that you can only instantiate each graph once and have written the code to accommodate this by instantiating the graph before the for loop begins.  The code will only generate one graph after the Stroke() call and no further graphs are created.  Any ideas?

```
$graph = new Graph(850,330);
$graph1 = new Graph(850,330);
$graph2 = new Graph(850,330);
$graph->SetScale('datint');
$graph1->SetScale('datint');
$graph2->SetScale('datint');
$graph->SetMargin(70,130,30,100);
$graph1->SetMargin(70,130,30,100);
$graph2->SetMargin(70,130,30,100);
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelFormatString('Y M d',true);

$graph1->xaxis->SetLabelFormatString('Y M d',true);
$graph2->xaxis->SetLabelFormatString('Y M d',true);
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
$graph1->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
$graph2->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
foreach($dates as $dkey=>$dvalue){

$graph->title->Set("Transfer rate for ".$siteName." in ".$tUnits."/second");
$graph->subtitle->Set("Dates: ".$dvalueL." to ".$dvalueH." for ".$siteName." AND monflag is ".$monFlag.".");

             $graph->yscale->ticks->Set(20, 10);
             if($maxT < 10) {
  $graph->yscale->ticks->Set(1,1);
}
else if(10 < $maxT && $maxT <= 1024) {
  $graph->yscale->ticks->Set(10, 2);
} else if(1024 < $maxT && $maxT <= 1048576) {
  $graph->yscale->ticks->Set(10, 5);
} else if(1048576 < $maxT && $maxT <= 1073741824) {
  $graph->yscale->ticks->Set(20, 10);
}

             $graph1->yscale->ticks->Set(20, 10);
if($maxC < 10) {
  $graph1->yscale->ticks->Set(1,1);
} else if(10 < $maxC && $maxC <= 1024) {
  $graph1->yscale->ticks->Set(10, 2);
} else if(1024 < $maxC && $maxC <= 1048576) {
  $graph1->yscale->ticks->Set(10, 5);
} else if(1048576 < $maxC && $maxC <= 1073741824) {
  $graph1->yscale->ticks->Set(20, 10);
}


$graph->SetMarginColor("#F0F0F0");
$graph->SetColor("#FFFFFF");
$graph1->title->Set("Compression ratio for ".$siteName);
$graph1->subtitle->Set("Dates: ".$dvalueL." to ".$dvalueH." for ".$siteName." AND monflag is ".$monFlag.".");
$graph1->SetMarginColor("#F0F0F0");
$graph1->SetColor("#FFFFFF");
$graph2->yscale->ticks->Set(20, 10);
if($maxL < 10) {
  $graph2->yscale->ticks->Set(1,1);
} else if(10 < $maxL && $maxL <= 1000) {
  $graph2->yscale->ticks->Set(10, 2);
} else if(1000 < $maxL && $maxL <= 10000) {
  $graph2->yscale->ticks->Set(10, 5);
} else if(10000 < $maxL && $maxL <= 1000000) {
  $graph2->yscale->ticks->Set(20, 10);
}

$graph2->title->Set("Lag time for ".$siteName);
$graph2->subtitle->Set("Dates: ".$dvalueL." to ".$dvalueH." for ".$siteName." AND monflag is ".$monFlag.".");


$graph2->SetMarginColor("#F0F0F0");
$graph2->SetColor("#FFFFFF");
$lineplot=new LinePlot($transferDataCad,$transerDate);
$lineplotT=new LinePlot($transferDataTech,$transferDate);
$lineplotT2=new LinePlot($transferDataLocal,$transferDate);
$lineplot->SetColor('red');
$lineplotT->SetColor('green');
$lineplotT2->SetColor('black');
$lineplot->SetLegend('Volume: CAD');
$lineplotT->SetLegend('Volume: TECH');
$lineplotT2->SetLegend('Volume: LOCAL');




$graph->img->SetImgFormat("jpeg");
$lineplot->SetWeight(2);
$lineplotT->SetWeight(2);
$lineplotT2->SetWeight(2);



$lineplot->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplotT->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplotT2->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$graph->Add($lineplot);
$graph->Add($lineplotT);
$graph->Add($lineplotT2);
$graph->xaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_TOP); 
$graph->yaxis->SetColor('blue','blue'); 
$graph->xaxis->SetColor('purple','purple'); 
$graph->xaxis->title->Set("Date");
$graph->yaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_RIGHT); 
$graph->yaxis->title->Set($tUnits."/second");

$lineplot1=new LinePlot($compDataCad,$compDate);
$lineplot1C=new LinePlot($compDataTech,$compDate);
$lineplot1C2=new LinePlot($compDataLocal,$compDate);
$lineplot1->SetColor('blue');
$lineplot1C->SetColor('orange');
$lineplot1C2->SetColor('purple');

$lineplot1->SetWeight(2);
$lineplot1C->SetWeight(2);
$lineplot1C2->SetWeight(2);
$lineplot1->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplot1C->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplot1C2->mark->SetType(MARK_X);



$lineplot1->SetLegend('Volume: CAD');
$lineplot1C->SetLegend('Volume: TECH');
$lineplot1C2->SetLegend('Volume: LOCAL');
$graph->legend->Pos(0.01,0.1,"right" ,"center");
$graph1->legend->Pos(0.01,0.1,"right" ,"center");

$graph1->img->SetImgFormat("jpeg");
$graph1->Add($lineplot1);
$graph1->Add($lineplot1C);
$graph1->Add($lineplot1C2);
$graph1->xaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_TOP); 
$graph1->yaxis->SetColor('blue','blue'); 
$graph1->xaxis->SetColor('red','red');
$graph1->xaxis->title->Set("Date");
$graph1->yaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_RIGHT); 
$graph1->yaxis->title->Set("Ratio");

$lineplot2=new LinePlot($lagDataCad,$lagDate);
$lineplot2C=new LinePlot($lagDataTech,$lagDate);
$lineplot2C2=new LinePlot($lagDataLocal,$lagDate);
$lineplot2->SetColor('blue');
$lineplot2C->SetColor('orange');
$lineplot2C2->SetColor('purple');

$lineplot2->SetWeight(2);
$lineplot2C->SetWeight(2);
$lineplot2C2->SetWeight(2);

$lineplot2->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplot2C->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplot2C2->mark->SetType(MARK_X);
$lineplot2->SetLegend('Volume: CAD');
$lineplot2C->SetLegend('Volume: TECH');
$lineplot2C2->SetLegend('Volume: LOCAL');
$graph2->legend->Pos(0.01,0.1,"right" ,"center");


$graph2->img->SetImgFormat("jpeg");
$graph2->Add($lineplot2);
$graph2->Add($lineplot2C);
$graph2->Add($lineplot2C2);
$graph2->xaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_TOP); 
$graph2->yaxis->SetColor('blue','blue'); 
$graph2->xaxis->SetColor('green','green');
$graph2->xaxis->title->Set("Date");
$graph2->yaxis->SetTitleSide(SIDE_RIGHT); 
$graph2->yaxis->title->Set("Seconds");
// Display the graphs


if($monFlag == 0){
    $graph->Stroke('/var/apps/asc/web/images/'.$siteName.$dTemp1.'tgraph.jpg');
    $graph1->Stroke('/var/apps/asc/web/images/'.$siteName.$dTemp1.'cgraph.jpg');
    $graph2->Stroke('/var/apps/asc/web/images/'.$siteName.$dTemp1.'lgraph.jpg');

}

if($monFlag == 1){
    $graph->Stroke('/var/apps/asc/web/images/'.$siteName.$dTemp1.$dTemp2.'tgraph.jpg');
    $graph1->Stroke('/var/apps/asc/web/images'.$siteName.$dTemp1.$dTemp2.'cgraph.jpg');
    $graph2->Stroke('/var/apps/asc/web/images'.$siteName.$dTemp1.$dTemp2.'lgraph.jpg');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a regular html file that will contain all of the graphs.
2. Call each graph using the `img` tag manually or with a php loop

When you use `img` tag to src the jpgraph's url, the strok'ed graph is treated as an image.  This way, you can have multiple graphs on each page, and keep the code for each graph separate.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I came across it searching for an answer how to add multiple jpgraph csim images to a single page.

My successful steps, based on the jpgraph example, were to use the following file (display.php) which uses the CSIM created in the separate image scripts ($_graphfilename1, $_graphfilename2)  to display multiple graphs. To display 2 graphs, you need three separate scripts, the 2 image scripts and the script to combine the display.

The key which was not clear in the jpgraph documentation examples was that each of the 2 image scripts must use different variable names e.g. $graph1 , $graph2 for the $graph variable, stroke these accordingly, and then reference these appropriately in the display.php script

```
    <?php

// The names of the graph scripts
$_graphfilename1 = 'projectcsim.php';
$_graphfilename2 = 'resultcsim.php';

// This is the filename of this HTML file
global $_wrapperfilename;
$_wrapperfilename = basename (__FILE__);

// Create a random mapname used to connect the image map with the image
$_mapname1 = '__mapname'.rand(0,1000000).'__';
$_mapname2 = '__mapname'.rand(0,1000000).'__';

// Get the graph scripts
require_once ($_graphfilename1);
require_once ($_graphfilename2);

// This line gets the image map and inserts it on the page
$imgmap1 = $graph1->GetHTMLImageMap($_mapname1);
$imgmap2 = $graph2->GetHTMLImageMap($_mapname2);
echo $imgmap1;
echo $imgmap2;

// Construct the <img> tags for Figure 1 &amp; 2 and rebuild the URL arguments
$imgtag1 = $graph1->GetCSIMImgHTML($_mapname1,$_graphfilename1);
$imgtag2 = $graph2->GetCSIMImgHTML($_mapname2,$_graphfilename2);
?>
<table border=0>
<tr><td valign="bottom">
<?php
echo $imgtag1;
?>
<br><b>Figure 1. </b>
</td></tr><tr>
<td valign="bottom">
<?php
echo $imgtag2;
?>
<br><b>Figure 2. </b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```